# Infinite loop in PagingSource when response is empty using Paging 3 library and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, paging, android-paging, android-paging-3

I'm using Paging 3 library and Retrofit to get data. My problem is that when the API response retrieve an empty list, instead of print nothing, it causes an infinite loop in my PagingSource class. How can I stop the loop? I want the possibility to get an empty response.

### **My PagingSource class:**

```
    val responseData = mutableListOf<DataAPI>()
class DataAPIPagingSource(private val token:String,private val apiCalls:APICalls) : PagingSource<Int,DataAPI>{
    
    override fun getRefreshKey(...):Int?{
        return null
    }
    override suspend fun load(params : LoadParams<Int>):LoadResult<Int,DataAPI>{
        return try{
            val currentPage = params.key ?: 1
            val response = apiCalls.getData(token)
            response.body()?.let{
                Result.Success(it)  
            }?: run{
                Result.Failure(response.message(),response.code())
            }
            val data = response.body()?.listData ?: emptyList()
            responseData.addAll(data)
            LoadResult.Page(responseData,if(currentPage ==1) null else -1),currentPage.plus(1)
            

        }catch(e:Exception){
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The load function returns `LoadResult.Page` when the load was successful, which has three values: `data`, `prevKey` and `nextKey`. Documentation for the `nextKey` says:

> `nextKey` - Key for next page if more data can be loaded in that direction, null otherwise

You always use `currentPage + 1` for the `nextKey` though, so paging thinks there are more pages to load and tries to load them. Set `nextKey` to `null` when there are no more data to load.